# php delete file.pdf before packaging

Tags: php, ajax, unlink

How do I go about deleting  instructions.pdf from a temp directory?

My web script creates temporary folders with a unique id and requests some files from another server.  One such file is "instructions.pdf".  I want to delete this file before the temporary folder gets packaged into a zip file.

I think the easiest way would be to overwrite these files using some PHP code AFTER the package is downloaded from the API but before the package is zipped up for the user. Understanding the steps in the process may make this easier to conceptualize.

a) User click "package source code"

b) Self hosted panel contacts API

c) API returns a project package (containing the instructions.pdf) this is a zip archive

d) Self hosted panel unzips the archive for processing

e) Self hosted panel adds plugins and other assets and makes some adjustments to the package

f) Self hosted panel creates a zip archive in the /files/temp folder for the user to download.

This means that I would add an additional step before f). "Delete the instructions.pdf from the package and replace with "this file on my server" before creating the zip archive."

I want to add new logic approximately where it reads "process plugins".  I need to do this in two places (same logic but a bit different for each platform) once for iOS and once for Android.  Same file handles both packages.

I have tried unlink but it's not deleting anything. Here is the code I am using without success:

```
   // delete pdf...
    if($fh = fopen($rootFolder . "instructions.pdf", 'w')){
    fclose($fh);
    unlink('instructions.pdf');
    }
```

the full php code is :

```
<?php   require_once("../../config.php");
        require_once("../../includes/zip.php");

    //who's logged in
    $guid = "";
    if(isset($_SESSION[APP_LOGGEDIN_COOKIE_NAME])) $guid = fnFormInput($_SESSION[APP_LOGGEDIN_COOKIE_NAME]);

    //init user object
    $thisUser = new User($guid);
    $thisUser -> fnLoggedInReq($guid);
    $thisUser -> fnUpdateLastRequest($guid, "1");

    //try to increase max execution time..This is only necessary on painfully slow servers!
    if(!ini_get('safe_mode')){ 
        @set_time_limit(120);
    }       

    //project vars posted in AJAX request...
    $appGuid = fnGetReqVal("appGuid", "", $myRequestVars);
    $whatPlatform = fnGetReqVal("whatPlatform", "", $myRequestVars);
    $saveToPath = "";
    $packageURL = "";

    //init some variables for the json result...        
    $bolPassed = true;
    $strMessage = "";

    //must have an app id...
    if(strlen($appGuid) < 5 || strlen($guid) < 5){
        $bolPassed = false;
        $strMessage .= "<br>No app id found";
    }       

    //must have a platoform selected...
    if(strlen($whatPlatform) < 1){
        $bolPassed = false;
        $strMessage .= "<br>There was a problem figuring out what platform to package the project for?";
    }       

    //create an app object so we can get the project name...
    if($bolPassed){

        //ceate an app object...
        $objApp = new App($appGuid);

        //make sure user can manage this app...
        $objApp->fnCanManageApp($thisUser->infoArray["guid"], $thisUser->infoArray["userType"], $appGuid, $objApp->infoArray["ownerGuid"]);

        //appAPIKey and project name comes from objApp
        $appAPIKey = $objApp->infoArray["apiKey"];
        $appAPISecret = $objApp->infoArray["appSecret"];
        $appName = $objApp->infoArray["name"];
        $projectName = $objApp->infoArray["projectName"];
        $projectName = fnCleanProjectName($projectName);
        $projectName = strtolower($projectName);
        $appIconURL = $objApp->infoArray["iconUrl"];
        $appVersion = $objApp->infoArray["version"];


    }//bolPassed



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //start functions

    //replace in text file function
    function fnReplaceText($filePath, $replaceWhat, $replaceWith){
        if(is_file($filePath)){
            if(is_readable($filePath)){
                $str = file_get_contents($filePath);
                if(strlen($str) > 0){   
                    //echo "<br> Replacing text in: " . $filePath;
                    $fp = fopen($filePath,"w");
                    $str = str_replace($replaceWhat,$replaceWith,$str);
                    if(fwrite($fp, $str, strlen($str))){
                        //echo " ~ SUCCESS";
                    }else{
                        //echo " ~ ERROR!";
                    }

                }else{
                    //echo "<br>This file is empty: " . $filePath;
                }
            }else{
                //echo "<br>File not readable: " . $filePath;
            }
        }else{
            //echo "<br>Not a file: " . $filePath;
        }
    }

    //delete a directory and all of it's contents..
    function delete_directory($dirname) {
       if (is_dir($dirname))
          $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
       if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
       while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
             if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                unlink($dirname."/".$file);
             else
                delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
          }
       }
       closedir($dir_handle);
       rmdir($dirname);
       return true;
    }

    //copies directory and all it's sub-directories
    function copy_directory($source, $destination){
        if(is_dir($source)){
            @mkdir($destination);
            chmod($destination, 0755);
            $directory = dir($source);
            chmod($directory, 0755);

            while(FALSE !== ($readdirectory = $directory->read())){
                if($readdirectory == '.' || $readdirectory == '..'){
                    continue;
                }
                $PathDir = $source . '/' . $readdirectory; 
                if(is_dir($PathDir)){
                    copy_directory($PathDir, $destination . '/' . $readdirectory );
                    chmod($destination . '/' . $readdirectory, 0755);
                    continue;
                }
                copy($PathDir, $destination . '/' . $readdirectory);
                chmod($destination . '/' . $readdirectory, 0755);
            }
            $directory->close();
        }else {
            copy($source, $destination);
            chmod($destination, 0755);
        }
    }   

    //calls buzztouch.com's API to build project. Returns a download URL for the .zipped up package
    function fnGetBuzztouchPackageUsingAPI($appGuid, $projectName, $appName, $iconURL, $platform, $version){

        //we'll be returning a download URL or an errors[] array...
        $errors = array();
        $packageURL = "";

        //key/value pairs to send in the request...
        $postVars = "";
        $fields = array(

            //needed by the buzztouch.com api to validate this request
            "apiKey" => urlencode(APP_BT_SERVER_API_KEY),
            "apiSecret" => urlencode(APP_BT_SERVER_API_KEY_SECRET),
            "command" => urlencode("packageProject"),

            //required by "packageProject" command...
            "appGuid" => urlencode($appGuid),
            "projectName" => urlencode($projectName),
            "appName" => urlencode($appName),
            "iconURL" => urlencode($iconURL),
            "platform" => urlencode($platform),
            "version" => urlencode($version)

        );

        //prepare the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key => $value){ 
            $postVars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&"; 
        }

        //setup api url
        $apiURL = rtrim(APP_BT_SERVER_API_URL, "/");

        //init a cURL object, set number of POST vars and the POST data
        $ch = curl_init($apiURL . "/app/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);

        //get JSON result from buzztouch API
        $jsonResult = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        //decode json vars
        if($jsonResult != ""){
            $json = new Json; 
            $decoded = $json->unserialize($jsonResult);
            if(is_object($decoded)){

                //init status and pacakgeURL
                $status = "";
                $packageURL = "";

                //must have a result...
                if(array_key_exists("result", $decoded)){
                    $results = $decoded -> result;

                    //must have a status...
                    if(array_key_exists("status", $results)){
                        $status = $results -> status;
                    }else{
                        $errors[] = "API result does not contain a required field: status missing.";
                    }

                }else{
                    $errors[] = "API result does not contain a required field: result missing.";
                }//key exists..

                //still no errors?
                if(count($errors) < 1){

                    //success means we'll get a package URL from the API...
                    if(strtoupper($status) == "SUCCESS"){
                        if(array_key_exists("packageURL", $results)){
                            $packageURL = $results -> packageURL;
                        }
                    }else{

                        //show the errors...
                        if(array_key_exists("errors", $results)){

                            $errorList = $results -> errors;
                            for($e = 0; $e < count($errorList); $e++){
                                $errors[] = $errorList[$e] -> message;
                            }

                        }else{
                            $errors[] = "buzztouch API returned an error but no details were provided";
                        }

                    }//success

                }//errors...

            }else{
                $errors[] = "buzztouch API return invalid JSON";
            }
        }else{
            $errors[] = "buzztouch API return invalid JSON";
        }

        //did we have errors?
        if(strlen($packageURL) > 0){
            return $packageURL;
        }else{
            return $errors;
        }

    }//fnPackageUsingAPI


    //downloads and saves a .zip from buzztouch.com so it can be processed locally.
    function fnDownloadAndSaveZip($packageURL, $saveAsLocalFileName){

        //create a file pointer for cURL to save to...
        $fp = fopen($saveAsLocalFileName, 'w');

        //init a cURL session to download the zip
        $ch = curl_init($packageURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

        $zipData = curl_exec($ch);

        //close cURL and file pointer...
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);                    

        //make sure .zip project was downloaded and saved!
        if(is_file($saveAsLocalFileName)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    //gets config data from this server's API
    function fnGetConfigData($appGuid, $appAPIKey, $appAPISecret){

        //post vars to using CURL to make an API call to the same box.
        $postVars = "";
        $fields = array(
            "apiKey" => urlencode($appAPIKey),
            "apiSecret" => urlencode($appAPISecret),
            "command" => urlencode("getAppData"),
            "appGuid" => urlencode($appGuid)
            );

        //prepare the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key => $value){ 
            $postVars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&"; 
        }

        //init a cURL object to this UR
        $ch = curl_init(rtrim(APP_URL, "/") . "/api/app/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);

        //get JSON result from buzztouch API
        $configDataString = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);    

        return $configDataString;
    }

    //end functions
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //validate...
    if($bolPassed){

        if(strlen($appAPIKey) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No API key found for this project?";
        }
        if(strlen($appAPISecret) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No App Secret found for this project?";
        }

        if(strlen($appName) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No application name found for this project?";
        }

        if(strlen($projectName) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No project name found for this project?";
        }           

        if(strlen($appIconURL) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No Icon URL found for this project?";
        }

        if(strlen($appVersion) < 1){
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "<br>No version found for this project?";
        }       

    }//bolPassed



    //if we have an API key then fetch project from buzztouch.com's API
    if($bolPassed){

        //temp directory path...
        $temp_directory = APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp";                     

        //remove previous .folders if they are still hanging around from last attempt...
        fnRemoveDirectory(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-iOS-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid);
        fnRemoveDirectory(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-Android-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid);

        //remove previous zip's if they are still hanging around from last attempt...
        if(is_file(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-iOS-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip")){
            @unlink(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-iOS-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip");
        }
        if(is_file(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-Android-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip")){
            @unlink(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/temp/" . $projectName . "-Android-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip");
        }

        //file names for the .zip we will be preparing...
        if(strtoupper($whatPlatform) == "IOS"){
            $saveToFolderName = $projectName . "-iOS-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip";
        }
        if(strtoupper($whatPlatform) == "ANDROID"){
            $saveToFolderName = $projectName . "-Android-BTv2.0-" . $appGuid . ".zip";
        }

        //save the folder in the /files/temp directory
        $saveToPath = "../../" . ltrim(APP_DATA_DIRECTORY, "/") . "/temp/" . $saveToFolderName;

        //root folder is where we are saving the all the unzipped files to...
        $rootFolder = str_replace(".zip", "", $saveToPath);

        //make sure we have a writable temp directory...
        if(is_dir("../../" . ltrim(APP_DATA_DIRECTORY, "/") . "/temp")){
            if(!is_writable("../../" . ltrim(APP_DATA_DIRECTORY, "/") . "/temp")){
                $bolPassed = false;
                $strMessage .= "The ../../" . ltrim(APP_DATA_DIRECTORY, "/") . "/temp directory is not writable by PHP. This folder needs write access.";
            }
        }else{
            $bolPassed = false;
            $strMessage .= "The ../../" . ltrim(APP_DATA_DIRECTORY, "/") . "/temp directory does not exist. This folder needs to exist and PHP needs write access to it. ";
        }

        //good so far...
        if($bolPassed){

            //packageURL comes form the buzztouch API
            $packageURL = fnGetBuzztouchPackageUsingAPI($appGuid, $projectName, $appName, $appIconURL, $whatPlatform, $appVersion);

            if(is_array($packageURL)){

                //flag as no good
                $bolPassed = false;

                //show the errors...
                for($e = 0; $e < count($packageURL); $e++){
                    $strMessage .= $packageURL[$e];
                }

            }else{

                //all good, download and save the file from the packageURL...
                if(!fnDownloadAndSaveZip($packageURL, $saveToPath)){
                    $bolPassed = false;
                    $strMessage .= "<br>An error occurred trying to download a package from the buzztouch API";
                }else{
                    //extract the .zip to the /temp directory..
                    if(is_file($saveToPath)){

                        $archive = new PclZip($saveToPath);
                        $list = $archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $rootFolder);
                        if(count($list) < 5 || !is_dir($rootFolder)){
                            $bolPassed = false;
                            $strMessage .= "There was a problem unzipping the package delivered by the buzztouch API. This can be caused by a few things. Is it possible that this is a Windows Server? This software does not run on Windows powered servers.";
                        }               

                    }else{

                        $bolPassed = false;
                        $strMessage .= "<br>There was a problem finding the downloaded package";
                    }

                }

            }//is_array errors

        }//bolPassed

        //at this point we should have a folder to use to create our new project...It may already be full of the 
        //contents from the project returned by the buzztouch API...
        if($bolPassed){

            if(is_dir($rootFolder)){

                //array holds all the files we've already added to the project - no duplicates allowed!
                $existingFiles = array();

                //get the BT_config.txt data from this server's API...
                $configDataString = fnGetConfigData($appGuid, $appAPIKey, $appAPISecret);
                if(strlen($configDataString) > 10){

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //iOS project...                
                    if(strtoupper($whatPlatform) == "IOS"){
                        $originalDelegateName = "BT_appDelegate";
                        $newDelegateName = $projectName . "_appDelegate";

                        //build directories if they don't exist already...
                        $makeFolders = array("BT_Config", "BT_Art", "BT_Video", "BT_Sound", "BT_Images", "BT_Docs", "BT_Plugins");
                        for($d = 0; $d < count($makeFolders); $d++){
                            if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/" . $makeFolders[$d])){
                                @mkdir($rootFolder . "/" . $makeFolders[$d]);
                            }
                        }

                        //over-write the config data...
                        if($fh = fopen($rootFolder . "/BT_Config/BT_config.txt", 'w')){
                            fwrite($fh, $configDataString);
                            fclose($fh);        
                        }

                        //download app icon from remote server...Could be .jpg or .png
                        if(strtolower(substr($appIconURL, -4)) == ".jpg"){
                            $icon = @imagecreatefromjpeg($appIconURL);
                        }else{
                            if(strtolower(substr($appIconURL, -4)) == ".png"){
                                $icon = @imagecreatefrompng($appIconURL);
                            }
                        }
                        if($icon){

                            //get icons original size...
                            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = @getimagesize($appIconURL);
                            if($width_orig > 0 && $height_orig > 0){

                                //create a few new sizes...
                                $sizes = array(57, 72, 114);
                                for($s = 0; $s < count($sizes); $s++){
                                    $thisSize = $sizes[$s];
                                    $width = $thisSize;
                                    $height = $thisSize;

                                    $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;
                                    if($width / $height > $ratio_orig){
                                       $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
                                    }else{
                                       $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
                                    }

                                    //resample
                                    $icon_scaled = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                                    @imagecopyresampled($icon_scaled, $icon, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

                                    //output
                                    @imagepng($icon_scaled, $rootFolder . "/BT_Art/Icon_" . $thisSize . ".png");

                                }//end for each size

                            }//if original width / height > 0
                        }//if icon...

                        //process plugins...
                        $strSql = " SELECT webDirectoryName FROM " . TBL_BT_PLUGINS;
                        $res = fnDbGetResult($strSql, APP_DB_HOST, APP_DB_NAME, APP_DB_USER, APP_DB_PASS);
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                            $tmpPath = APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/plugins" . $row["webDirectoryName"];
                            if(is_dir($tmpPath)){
                                if(is_readable($tmpPath)){

                                    //copy all the files from the source-ios directory into the BT_plugins folder...
                                    $iosFolder = $tmpPath . "/source-ios";
                                    if(is_dir($iosFolder)){
                                        $newFolder = $rootFolder . "/BT_Plugins/" . ltrim($row["webDirectoryName"], "/");
                                        @mkdir($newFolder, 0755);

                                        //copy / merge every file in the /source-ios folder to this newly created folder...
                                        if($handle = opendir($iosFolder)){
                                            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                if(strlen($file) > 5){
                                                    if(is_file($iosFolder . "/" . $file)){
                                                        if($file != ".DS_Store" && $file != "__MACOSX"){

                                                            //don't include if it's already been added
                                                            if(!in_array($file, $existingFiles)){

                                                                //copy the file...
                                                                copy($iosFolder . "/". $file, $newFolder . "/" . $file);

                                                                //if this is a .m or .h file, replace the app delegate name...
                                                                $lastTwoChars = substr($file, strlen($file) - 2, 2);
                                                                if(strtoupper($lastTwoChars) == ".H" || strtoupper($lastTwoChars) == ".M"){
                                                                    fnReplaceText($newFolder . "/" . $file, $originalDelegateName, $newDelegateName);
                                                                }

                                                            }//existing files

                                                            //remember file...
                                                            $existingFiles[] = $file;

                                                        }//not .DS_Store                                                                    
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }//end while    
                                        }//if open source-ios
                                    }//is_dir /source-ios
                                }//is_readable for this plugin...
                            }//is_dir for this plugin...
                        }//end while plugins..
                    }
                    //end iOS
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //Android project...                
                    if(strtoupper($whatPlatform) == "ANDROID"){
                        $originalDelegateName = "BT_appDelegate";
                        $newDelegateName = $projectName . "_appDelegate";
                        $originalPackageName = "com.buzzTouch";
                        $newPackageName = "com." . $projectName;

                        //build directories if they don't exist already...
                        $makeFolders = array("assets", "bin", "gen", "jar", "res", "src");
                        for($d = 0; $d < count($makeFolders); $d++){
                            if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/" . $makeFolders[$d])){
                                @mkdir($rootFolder . "/" . $makeFolders[$d]);
                            }
                        }

                        //make /assets sub-directories if they don't exist already...
                        $makeFolders = array("BT_Video", "BT_Audio", "BT_Docs");
                        for($d = 0; $d < count($makeFolders); $d++){
                            if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/assets/" . $makeFolders[$d])){
                                @mkdir($rootFolder . "/assets/" . $makeFolders[$d]);
                            }
                        }

                        //make /res sub-directories if they don't exist already...
                        $makeFolders = array("anim", "drawable", "drawable-hdpi", "drawable-ldpi", "drawable-mdpi", "layout", "values");
                        for($d = 0; $d < count($makeFolders); $d++){
                            if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/res/" . $makeFolders[$d])){
                                @mkdir($rootFolder . "/res/" . $makeFolders[$d]);
                            }
                        }

                        //make /src sub-directories if they don't exist already...
                        if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/src/com")) @mkdir($rootFolder . "/src/com");
                        if(!is_dir($rootFolder . "/src/com/" . str_replace("com.", "", $newPackageName))) @mkdir($rootFolder . "/src/com/" . str_replace("com.", "", $newPackageName));

                        //over-write (or create) the config data...
                        if($fh = fopen($rootFolder . "/assets/BT_config.txt", 'w')){
                            fwrite($fh, $configDataString);
                            fclose($fh);        
                        }

                        //get app's icon, could be .jpg or .png
                        if(strtolower(substr($appIconURL, -4)) == ".jpg"){
                            $icon = @imagecreatefromjpeg($appIconURL);
                        }else{
                            if(strtolower(substr($appIconURL, -4)) == ".png"){
                                $icon = @imagecreatefrompng($appIconURL);
                            }
                        }
                        if($icon){

                            //get icons original size...
                            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = @getimagesize($appIconURL);
                            if($width_orig > 0 && $height_orig > 0){

                                //create a few new sizes...
                                $sizes = array(36, 48, 57, 72);

                                //save them here...
                                $drawableFolders = array("drawable-ldpi", "drawable-mdpi", "drawable", "drawable-hdpi");

                                for($s = 0; $s < count($sizes); $s++){
                                    $thisSize = $sizes[$s];
                                    $width = $thisSize;
                                    $height = $thisSize;

                                    $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;
                                    if($width / $height > $ratio_orig){
                                       $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
                                    }else{
                                       $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
                                    }

                                    //resample
                                    $icon_scaled = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                                    @imagecopyresampled($icon_scaled, $icon, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

                                    //output
                                    @imagepng($icon_scaled, $rootFolder . "/res/" . $drawableFolders[$s] . "/icon.png");

                                }//end for each size

                            }//width / height
                        }//if icon...



                        /*
                            Android Activitites: The AndroidManifest.xml file has a line that reads:
                            <!-- replace this with list of activity includes -->
                            We'll end up replacing that line with a list of activity files included in 
                            the project. It's important that each .java class in the Plugin be an Android Activity. 
                            If another .java class is needed to support the plugin it needs to be a child-class
                            within the main activity class. In other words, it's assumed that all .java class
                            files found in the source-android folder are Android Activities.                                                        
                        */
                        $activitiesList = "";

                        /* 
                            Using Maps: The AndroidManifest.xml file has a line that reads:
                            <!-- <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> -->
                            We'll end up replacing that line with an uncommented version like this:
                            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
                            if the application is using a BT_screen_map plugin.
                        */
                        $bolUsingMaps = false;


                        //process all the plugins...
                        $strSql = " SELECT webDirectoryName FROM " . TBL_BT_PLUGINS;
                        $res = fnDbGetResult($strSql, APP_DB_HOST, APP_DB_NAME, APP_DB_USER, APP_DB_PASS);
                        if($res){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                                $tmpPath = APP_PHYSICAL_PATH . APP_DATA_DIRECTORY . "/plugins" . $row["webDirectoryName"];
                                if(is_dir($tmpPath)){
                                    if(is_readable($tmpPath)){

                                        //look for source code...For Android we don't make any folder, we just copy the 
                                        //contents of the source-android to the appropriate directory in the Android project

                                        $audioDir = $rootFolder . "/assets/BT_Audio";
                                        $videoDir = $rootFolder . "/assets/BT_Video";
                                        $docsDir = $rootFolder . "/assets/BT_Docs";
                                        $srcDir = $rootFolder . "/src/com/" . str_replace("com.", "", $newPackageName);
                                        $layoutDir = $rootFolder . "/res/layout";
                                        $drawableDir = $rootFolder . "/res/drawable";

                                        $androidFolder = $tmpPath . "/source-android";
                                        if(is_dir($androidFolder)){

                                            //copy every file in the /source-android folder to the proper Android folder...
                                            if($handle = opendir($androidFolder)){
                                                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                    if(strlen($file) > 5){
                                                        if(is_file($androidFolder . "/" . $file)){
                                                            if($file != ".DS_Store" && $file != "__MACOSX"){
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You PHP code is too big for anyone here to read.

maybe you're doing it wrong from here:

```
// delete pdf...
if($fh = fopen($rootFolder . "instructions.pdf", 'w')){
    fclose($fh);
    unlink('instructions.pdf');
}
```

change it to (use [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists) as you don't need to read the file):

```
// delete pdf...
if(file_exists($rootFolder . "instructions.pdf"){
    unlink($rootFolder . "instructions.pdf");
}
```

you should have permissions on that file.

Comment: i give /temp 777 but it's still not working and the repackage process loaded without stop

Comment: you need to have permissions on that file also ... not directory. It doesn't need to have 777 to delete it.

Comment: i hope there some one can help with this :(